# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

Tags: java, eclipse, string, substring

Hi I wrote a java code to find longest word made of other words. My logic is to read the list of words from the text file and add each word into an array (In the text the words are sorted and there will be only one word in each line) After that we check if each element in the array has other elemnts as substrings. If so we count the number of substrings. The element with maximum number of substrings will be the result

The code is running when I give a text file wih only two words. But when there are more than two words I am getting following error

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3

I feel the error is occuring in this line if(s.charAt(i1)==w.charAt(j1))

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.lang.reflect.Array;
  public class Parser
  {
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String [] addyArray = null;

    FileReader inFile = new FileReader ("sample.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (inFile);
    String line = "";
    int a = 0;
    int size=0;
    String smallestelement = "";

    while(in.ready())
    {
        line=in.readLine();
        while (line != null && line != "\n")
        {
            size++;
            System.out.println(size);
            line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) line = "\n";
        }
    }
    addyArray = new String[size];
    FileReader inFile2 = new FileReader ("sample.txt");
    BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader (inFile2);
    String line2 = "";

    while(in2.ready())
    {
        line2 = in2.readLine();


        while (line2 != null && line2 != "\n")
        {

            addyArray[a] = line2;


            System.out.println("Array"+addyArray[a]);
            line2 = in.readLine();
            a++;
            if (line2 == null) line2 = "\n";
        }

    }


    int numberofsubstrings=0;
    int[] substringarray= new int[size];

    int count=0,no=0;

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{       
    System.out.println("sentence "+addyArray[i]);
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        System.out.println("word "+addyArray[j]);

        String w,s;
        s=addyArray[i].trim();
        w=addyArray[j].trim();

        try{
            for(int i1=0;i1<s.length();i1++)
            {
                if(s.equals(w)&& s.indexOf(addyArray[j-1].trim()) == -1)
                {}
            else
            {
                if(s.charAt(i1)==w.charAt(0))
                {                   
                   for(int j1=0;j1<w.length();j1++,i1++)
                   {
                     if(s.charAt(i1)==w.charAt(j1)) //I feel the error is occuring here
                     { count=count+1;}
                       if(count==w.length())
                       {no=no+1;count=0;};  

                   }
                }
              }
            }
              System.out.println(no);
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        substringarray[i]=no;
        no=0;

        }
    }   



        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Substring array"+substringarray[i]);
        }
    Arrays.sort(substringarray);  
    int max=substringarray[0];

    System.out.println("Final result is"+addyArray[max]+size);

}
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
 for(int j1=0;j1<w.length();j1++,i1++)
```

On each iteration through the loop, you're incrementing `i1` as well as `j1`. `i1` could already be at the end of `s`, so after you've incremented it, `s.charAt(i1)` is going to be invalid.

Two asides:

- You should look at `String.regionMatches`
- Using consistent indentation and sensible whitespace can make your code *much* easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

When you use string.charAt(x), you must check that it is not beyond string length.
[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) shows that you will get "IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string". And in your particular case, you are only validating in the loop that you are under w length, so it will fail.

As SO already said, the loop runs only taking into account w length, so in case you have a shorter s, it will raise that exception. Check the condition so it goes up to the shorter string or rethink the process.

Comment: Yes doing a check everytime for the charAt will fix the issue only put a bandage over the issue. This is not the root cause of the problem though. I would therefore not recommend using the solution. Also this may cause other issues in the code latter on.

Answer (score 1):

A few tips:

First, always include the full stack trace when you are asking for debugging help. It should point to the exact line number the issue is happening on.

Second, your issue is likely in your most inner loop `for(int j1=0;j1<w.length();j1++,i1++)` you are incrementing `i1` in addition to `j1` this will cause `i1` to eventually go beyond the size of String `s`

Finally, you should consider using the [String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method for Strings or even a Regular Expression.